# How to access unmounted drives?

Tags: drive

I've got three drives. One with my install on it and the other two are from my old windows install.
I want to keep those drives as they are because I do need to get windows back at some point.  How can I access them through Ubuntu without making windows hate them?
I used to be able to access them under other locations.

Comment: I'd add them to `/etc/fstab` (file system table) but firstly ensure you have fast-boot & hibernate disabled in windows. I don't know what you mean by '*windows hate them*' as I've never had issues with Ubuntu writing to my ntfs partitions, but I probably consider *what*, *where* & *when* I write data to a foreign file system owned by another OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can access drives formatted in *ntfs*, the MS Windows file system, and will do seamlessly as long as the file system is "clean", i.e. consistent. Thus, you could leave the drives formatted in ntfs, and just connect to them by clicking the drives in the left pane of Files.

You should not use ntfs for too long without having Windows. MS Windows is the only system that has comprehensive tools to check and repair an ntfs file system. Thus, as long as you do not have windows, you are not able for an in-depth check and repair of the file system. Although Linux has the `ntfsfix` tool which allows checking ntfs file systems, it only allows for basic repairs.

So the advice is: if you use the ntfs file system, you also need to have Windows around. If these are fixed drives, quickly have windows back. If the drives are removable, then you can periodically connect them to a Windows system for file system check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a forensic data recovery tool called `testdisk` to list the contents of partitons. The program also has a feature to list and copy the files in a partition without mounting the partiton.

One problem with windows and linux systems sharing and writing to `ntfs` partitons has to do with the way you exit from windows. If for example you hibernated your computer from windows and booted into ubuntu from the `grub` splash screen, the next time you boot up your system,  all the changes you make to the `ntfs` partition which is shared with windows will be erased as windows will reload the previous `ntfs` partiton structure without verifying if changes have been made to the partiton while windows was in hibernation. It'll simply continue from where it left off, if you've deleted files while on ubuntu, those files will be listed in `windows explorer` but their contents will likely have been corrupted. All new files you created while using the `ntfs` partition in ubuntu will be lost -as if they were never created in ubuntu.

So if you want to use Ubuntu alongside windows and have them share a partiton, always take care to properly shutdown windows before booting up ubuntu(or any linux distro) and using the partitons.

Other than that windows can share `ntfs`, `exFAT` and even `FAT` partitons safely with any linux distro.